# Exibir mensagens do utilizador

Tags: php, sql

Eu tenho duas tabelas, uma de `utilizadores` onde guardo o `username`e o `id`, e tenho uma outra `chat` onde guardo os campos `sender` e o `reciever`, que são os id's de utilizador de quem recebeu e enviou mensagem. 
Agora, como posso exibir que o utilizador logado com o `id=6` tem mensagens trocadas com o `id=11` e o `id=17`.

O utilizador pode ter 10 mensagens trocadas com o user `id=11` e uma mensagem só trocada com o `id=17`. Eu quero apenas que apareçam duas linhas dizendo que o utilizador `id=6` tem mensagens trocadas, neste caso com dois utilizadores.

Desta forma eu recebo todas as mensagens que o utilizador logado com `id=6` tem com os outros utilizadores

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM chat WHERE reciever = $id
UNION
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE sender = $id";
```

Se o utilizador for `id=6`eu recebo 10 mensagens que este utilizador trocou com o utilizador `id=11` e uma mensagem que ele trocou com o utilizador `id=17`

Comment: Dê um exemplo para que possamos ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `INNER JOIN` para fazer essa consulta.

```
SELECT
    chat.id,
    IF(chat.sender = 6, utilizadores_reciever.username,  utilizadores_sender.username) as username
FROM
    chat
    INNER JOIN utilizadores as utilizadores_sender ON (chat.sender = utilizadores_sender.id)
    INNER JOIN utilizadores as utilizadores_reciever ON (chat.reciever = utilizadores_reciever.id)
WHERE
    chat.sender = 6 OR chat.reciever = 6
GROUP BY 
    IF(chat.sender = 6, utilizadores_reciever.id,  utilizadores_sender.id)
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, era mesmo isso. Nessa consulta, como eu poderei aplicar o seguinte: `INNER JOIN photos AS p ON (user.photo_p_id=p.id )` Ou seja, eu tenho uma tabela `photos ` com o campo `id` e na tabela do `user` eu guardo o `id` correspondente à tabela `photos`. Queria mostrar a foto do utilizador, mas tenho que através do `photo_p_id` na tabela `utilizador` corresponder ao id da foto da tabela `photos`

Answer (score 0):

Quando o utilizador 6 troca mensagens, ele pode estar na posição de `sender` ou `receiver`, então precisamos fazer uma consulta que contemple as duas situações:

```
SELECT sender FROM chat WHERE receiver = 6
UNION
SELECT receiver FROM chat WHERE sender = 6
```

Quando o utilizador 6 for o `sender`, o outro utilizador será o `receiver` e vice-versa. O resultado da consulta acima mostrará os todos utilizadores que trocaram mensagens com o utilizador 6.

Comment: Pedro, ao postar algum código que não seja em uma linha, use markdown ou simplesmente dê `control+k`  com o código selecionado.

Comment: obrigado pela dica (Y)